# Filter out Early Access games from Steam store

Tags: steam

Is there a way to configure Steam to filter **out** early access games from the store?
In other words only show non-early access games in the store.

Comment: Don't go to the Early Access Category?

Comment: @Assylum That won't work because if games are tagged with multiple categories, for example early access and indie then it will still show up in the indie category.

Comment: The only way would be to ask the Enhanced Steam authors to include that but there is no way to do it on the Steam Client.

Comment: I mainly notice them as advertisements in the Steam update news dialog window that pops up, as well as the slide deck on the main page and Spotlight.  I was not going to the Early Access page.  I'll give it a few more days to see if anyone has any other ideas, else @kalina gets the answer points.  Thanks.

Comment: That would be a great option to have. Steam is already packed with all kinds of spammy DLCs, and sorting out through early access makes it even harder to find real games :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With the new released update, you can actually hide Early Access Games from the carousel and the "Recently Updated Box" as well as the "New Games on Steam" Box.

Just click the little customize box and you can choose what to see there. In the carousel, this box only appears once you mouse over it.

[image: SCreenshot of Feature]

Answer (score 4):

Steam hides early access games from the "new releases" section of the store and provides a dedicated [Early Access page](http://store.steampowered.com/genre/Early%20Access) to find new early access games. However, there isn't a general feature available in either the Steam client or the store website that allows you to completely remove early access games from the store.

Comment: They don't hide early access from new releases. I just checked the RPG category, and within top 10 new releases there's at least 2 early access

Comment: Not for I - checked 60, 0 early access present, couple of pre-orders in there and the rest were released games. Note if you switch to Top Sellers/Coming Soon/Specials and then change back that it currently doesn't seem to change back to the New Releases tab and you have to reload the page.

Answer (score 4):

This is now something you can disable by clicking your username -> Preferences -> Uncheck "Show Early Access titles"

[image]